# Proving that one score is not dependent on the other - interval data - R - Spearman correlation?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, spearman-rho

I want to attempt to answer the following hypothesis

A continuous scale (measured by an understanding score of 0-2) has a positive influence on consumers’ understanding of an eco-label (understanding measured by a score of 0-12).

In other words, I want to prove through a test, that in fact it doesn't really matter what your initial understanding score of 0-12 is, it will not affect your continuous scale score, because the continuous scale is easy to understand.

I therefore feel I almost want to prove the opposite of a correlation.

I consider both bits of data to be interval data. I am using R.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The "continuous scale" is a continuous variable in [0,2]? While eco-label is ordinal in {1,2,...12}? Your hypothesis is that higher/lower scores in the "continuous scale" (give it a name) does not result in higher/lower scores on the eco-label?

Comment: People are given a score based on their understanding of a label when testing them on the grading system of it. This score is 0, 1 or 2. My hypothesis is that understanding increases when presented with the grading system. In other words, it doesn't matter if you have an initial low score of knowledge of eco-labels, because the grading score makes it easy to understand! I hope that makes sense now...

Comment: So the "continuous scale" is ordinal {0,1,2}? Or is it interval? What type of variable is eco-label, ordinal {1,2,...,12}? Or interval?